# how to play video from any kind of url in video view android

Tags: android, android-videoview

We have some set of video url and are showing from link preview. So that in order to see video we have done like this,

```
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoPath("https://www.yyy.com/watch?v=werwsdf");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
```

if url ends with .mp4 it works, if not it wont work. Also if i put youtube url it wont support.
Therefore is there any api to play in video view of android widget in listview itself.

Comment: You should use MediaPlayer if you want to play mp4.

Comment: to play video why you have used webView

Comment: It's not really the URL that's the problem, it's what the web server is sending you. If you are being sent back an HTML page with an embedded video (like YouTube), then why would you expect a video to be played?

Comment: Use `Video View` functionality provided by `Official Android` which is better then to use `Web View`.

Comment: If you are playing the videos from YouTube it is better to use YouTube android player API

Comment: Your tag says videoview but you are using webview. ?..Use videoView http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html like @jaydroider said.

Comment: Sorry for wrong code. Now i edited the code. This is what we are using. Please take a look.